# TypeError: new(): data must be a sequence (got numpy.float64)

Tags: python, pytorch

I  do not know what to do with this problem.  I am running a model training.  The following part is what I got

```
 mean_train = torch.Tensor(np.mean(train_vertices, axis=0))
 TypeError: new(): data must be a sequence (got numpy.float64)
```

My code is:

```
mean_train = torch.Tensor(np.mean(train_vertices, axis=0))
std_train = torch.Tensor(np.std(train_vertices, axis=0))
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `Tensor` with `tensor` (note the difference in case)?  (I noticed that in the [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html), tensors are constructed with the lowercase `tensor`.)

Comment: That isn't all your code... what is `train_vertices`? Is it by chance a `numpy.float64`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have a `numpy` array and you want to create a pytorch tensor from it. You can use `torch.from_numpy` to achieve this. Note that `torch.from_numpy` expects an `np.ndarray` not a `np.float64` so you'll need to figure out your shapes.

However, if you don't *need* numpy, you can just use pytorch from the jump. Pytorch will likely have the functions you needed from numpy anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a `Tensor`, that could be autograded (modified with autograd), then you can only have iterable objects, like `numpy.array()`, `list()` and etc and you just need to check if your `np.mean(train_vertices, axis=0)` is by any chance a scalar.

If you want to create a tensor, that just needs to be a tensor, but would not be modified, then you can use `torch.tensor(np.mean(train_vertices, axis=0))`

P.S. More about it here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.tensor.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can try `torch.as_tensor()` without a cast to numpy array first.